# Matching and Extract from text file in Python

Tags: python, string, file

I am trying to read from a very large file which contains my "specific searched string" , if that string is found extract some 20-30 line after that point. The file is very large and contains many non-printable characters.

```
with open("C:/folder_1/issue_1/mem_3_logs.txt") as file:
    sli = None
    for line in file:
        if line.rstrip() == 'POOL ID, 0':
            file.seek(0) # reset pointer
            sli = islice(file, 0, 31) # get lines 3-5, o based indexing
            break

File "<ipython-input-17-cd7bb950144a>", line 1
    with open("C:/folder_1/issue_1/mem_3_logs.txt") as file:
                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to the encoding of the file. Instead of `open` function I would use `codecs.open`, for which you would have to `import codecs` first. Once you import it you should use the following syntax: `codecs.open("C:/folder_1/issue_1/mem_3_logs.txt", "r", "utf-8")`. If still doesn't work, try changing the encoding from `utf-8` to `Windows-1252` or `latin-1` or `utf-16` or `utf-16le`. One of those will work for sure :D

Comment: codecs.open("C:/folder_1/issue_1/mem_3_logs.txt", "r", "utf-8"),did these changes,but while running getting this as output runfile('C:/folder_1/issue_1/MemoryLeak.py', wdir='C:/folder_1/issue_1') <itertools.islice object at 0x000001D564F4B868>

Comment: You cannot run a loop over the file lines (for loop) and then pretend resetting the pointer (file.seek). This should not be done this way. For solving it try to do a `file.readlines()` at the beginning in order to get a list of the lines and then you will be able to use the list instead of the file stream

Comment: If I managed to help you in your problem, please consider upvoting my message and selecting it as accepted answer.